# admin/config/people/accounts/fields not displaying

Tags: users

I am new to drupal and have inherited a site.
I want to tidying and edit some of the fields n the user profile that already have been added, however 
admin/config/people/accounts/fields does not appear as a tab in admin/config/people/accounts
and nothing happens if i try to access admin/config/people/accounts/fields directly.

How can I enable this tab?

Comment: What Drupal version is it? And how outdated is core and modules? ;)

Comment: it is drupal 7.23, I have run the update script and all appears up to date in admin/reports/updates

Comment: here is a screen shot to the updates page [link]http://oa-admin.co.uk/modules.png[/link]

Comment: Are there any custom modules or themes or hacked code in core or contrib modules & themes? Also, it is always worth checking the recent log messages and status report pages for errors.

Answer (score 1):

The page you are looking for is provided by Field UI core module. Go to /admin/modules and enable it.

Comment: Brilliant. Yes it was disabled. Thanks for your help

Comment: @user1685846 glad it worked. Have a nice stay with us :) I hope you have seen [intro](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/about) already. Consider changing name to non-default, and hang with us to ask [solid questions](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).